# Alternative to Django Subclassing Related Models

Tags: django, django-models

Designing a quiz site that will feature a variety of question types. I have a Quiz Model class and then will have different models for each of the question types. So something like:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

class TextQuestion(models.Model): ...

class MultipleChoiceQuestion(models.Model): ...
```

My first idea was to have each of the question types subclass a Question model class. But I've read in 2 scoops of Django that concrete model inheritance is a bad idea. I could have `ForeignKey`s in each QuestionType subclass pointing back to the quiz, but this is limiting.

It seems like I'd have to query each type separately and there'd be no way to just get all the Questions. In the view for each quiz, I want to be able to do something like `Quizvar.question_set.all()`.

This seems like a common issue. What's the best way to design these related models? Is there a common technique? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Django can't automatically `union` objects from different sql tables.  So you have to have some intermediate table (for example concrete base `Question` class).

BTW, look at [django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Just because something is usually a bad idea, doesn't mean it is always a bad idea.

In your case, questions are a object that users will want to manage specifically, so having them as a concrete class would work fine as is, and then you can perform a query like: `Quizvar.question_set.all()` on a `models.py` set up like this:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

class Question(models.Model)
    question = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)

class TextQuestion(Question):
    pass
class MultipleChoiceQuestion(Question):
    pass
```

There are some downsides/issues of an approach like this, for example there will be a `Question` table in the database that may lead to a duplication of information. Also, this means that the response type is fixed very tightly to the question, and a user needs to pick that well ahead of time, and couldn't (easily) change from on question response to another if they need to.

Another approach would be to have a generic question, with a related response type, like so:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()

class Question(models.Model)
    question = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response)

class Response(models.Model):
    pass

class TextResponse(Response):
    length = ...

class NumberResponse(Response):
    minimum = ...
    maximum = ...

class MultipleChoiceResponse(Response):
    choices = ...
```

You would then just need to makes sure there were edit options to edit the response inline.